# Playing a sound only once during collisions

Tags: android, andengine

So recently i thought i figured out a solution for it, only to find out it doesnt work when i have more than one of the same object type added to the level.

What i was doing is iterating through my different list of objects and checking if any of them are colliding with the player, if they are i play the sound for that one colliding with the player and then i set the boolean for the sound to true, meaning the sound has been played now.

When their are no collisions going on or if the current object being iterated isnt colliding with the player i set the sound boolean back to false. So as you probably can see, there is a issue when there is more than one of the same objects added because one of them will set the boolean to false and the sound will be played over and over as long as the player is colliding with one of the objects.

So i have run out of solutions to fix this so i am seeking out help.

Thanks anyone who can offer assistance.

Answer (score 0):

set it to `true` when the collision is detected, only set it to `false` once the sound has completed playing.

Comment: The problem is during a Collision checking i have a method like "CheckSquareCollisions". All of the square object types are added to a linkedlist, and then i iterate through them to see which one the player is colliding with. So when one is colliding i play the sound, then if its not colliding i set the boolean to false. The problem is the player can only collide with one object at a time. That means he wont be colliding with say the other four square objects added to the list. Therefore the boolean will be set to false..and the sound will be played again. Thats the issue now.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like a soundmanager class? Instead of telling the sound to play, tell the soundmanager to play that sound. The manager then plays the sound and ignores other requests to play that sound until it's done. Per jmr's suggestion, the key here is not to set the boolean to false when he's not colliding, it'll be set to false when the manager recognizes the sound as done playing.

Incidentally, doing it this way has the benefit of allowing additional logic in the manager. Rather than restrict it to only one of a sound at a time, you might allow the manager to play the same sound twice if the second request was, say, halfway after the first. Or alternatively for some sounds you might want them to queue and wait their turn to be played.